# Python Calling a function in another function

Tags: python, scope

I am reading the book *Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner* by **Mike Dawson** and I was struck by a question that I had regarding functions.

Observing the code below

```
def func_1():
    name = input('What is your name?')
def func_2():
    print(name)

func_2()
```

I know that I cannot call the variable `name` in function 2 as it is local to function 1.

However, why can I call a function inside another function and then find the value of the user's input as such below?

```
def func_1():
    name = input('What is your name?')
    return name
def func_2():
    user_input = func_1()
    print(user_input)

func_2()
```

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? The calling of the function, or the `return`ing of the value to the caller?

Comment: Because you `return` the value

Comment: @deceze calling a function inside another function.

Comment: `func_1` returns a value in the second example, you are storing the value returned in a variable called `user_input` then printing it.

Comment: Try removing `return name`

Comment: I think the confusion is about understanding scoping, and why `func_1` can be called inside `func_2` but `name` can't be called within `func_2`. This is putting aside what the `return` is responsible for.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is even related, but does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45042273/why-can-i-use-a-variable-in-a-function-before-it-is-defined-in-python) have anything to do with your question? Can you clarify what exactly is confusing you?

Comment: You call a function (`input`) in another function (`func_1`) in your first example, too.

Comment: It's because `func_1()` is in the global space. If `func_1()` had been defined inside another scope (such as inside a class, another namespace or function) then you wouldn't be able to access it from `func_2()`

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This seems like a clear question and a reasonable mis-understanding for a beginner

Comment: @Chris_Rands thank you very much I was very confused and didn't know what the book was referring to! Please upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important thing to consider here is the **scope** of the variable and/or function names you're using. **Global** scope means everything can see it, whether it's at the top level, inside a function, or even inside a method, which is inside a class.

**Local** scope means it's locked within the context of that block, and nothing outside of the block can see it. In your case, that block is a function.

*(Note that this is a mild simplification and more complex rules exist around modules and includes, but this is a reasonable starter for 10...).*

In your example above, the function has been defined at the global level, so its name, `func_1` has **global** scope (you might also say that it is in the "global namespace". That means that anything can see it, including code inside other functions.

Conversely, the variable `name` has **local scope**, inside `func_1`, which means it is only visible inside `func_1`, and nowhere else.

When you `return name`, you're passing *the value of* `name` back to whatever called that function. That means that the `user_input = func_1()` receives the value that was returned and stores it in a new variable, called `user_input`.

The actual variable `name` is still only visible to `func_1`, but that value has been exposed to outside functions by `return`ing it.

**Edit:** As requested by @Chris_Rands:

There is a function in Python that will give you a dictionary containing of all the **global** variables currently available in the program.

This is the `globals()` function. You can check something is at global scope by seeing if it is in this dictionary:

```
def func_1():
    name = input('What is your name?')
def func_2():
    print(name)

func_1_is_global = 'func_1' in globals()  # value is 'True'
name_is_global = 'name' in globals()      # value is 'False'
```

**One additional edit for completeness:** I state above that you're passing the value of `name` back. This is not *strictly* true as Python is pass-by-reference, but the waters get murky here and I didn't want to confuse the issue. More details here for the interested observer: [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: It would be good to also mention that `func_1` *is* scoped to be called by `func_2` and why. A small blurb about global/local scope would help here.

Comment: You read my mind, was just updating accordingly. I'll add a tad more about local vs. global too.

Comment: I think it would also be good to clarify that you are returning the _value_ of `name` and not the variable `name` itself. The OP seems to be confused because he thinks that `name` somehow becomes accessible in `func_2` upon returning it from `func_1`.

Comment: @ChristianDean I've changed the wording as requested.

Answer (score 0):

func_2 calls func1, which returns a value which you can print inside func_2. In your first example func_2 cannot see a local variable of function_1.