# Python error: function not defined in class

Tags: python, function, methods

I'm just starting to learn python with a little background in Java and keep running into this error whenever I try to run my code. output and error message

[image: output and error message]

Here are the methods I've wrote in this class. methods involved, aside from the very last one

[image: methods involved, aside from the very last one]

I've checked multiple times and it isn't a spelling error. I don't understand why I'm not able to call one method in another from the same class.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to access methods within the same class, you have to use the word **self**.. And for that word to be valid, each method has to have it as its first parameter.

That is to say, you would have defined the above methods as follows::

`def main(self): self.run()`

then on run::
`def run(self): #do your stuff down here`

please do take into consideration the tabbing character of python as stackoverflow hasn't allowed me to do that, or I am less informed of how to do it

Answer (score 1):

```py
class Hello:

    def main(self):
        print("print")
        self.run()
    def run(self):
        print("run")

        
hello = Hello()

hello.main()
```

Thank you

Comment: This should work in outside class mechanism(function based).... But for methods in class, order is not that much useful

Comment: Yash, I did saw the concept and got too know that self term if more useful thank you for letting me know!!

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: @Yatin, self keyword carries the instance of the class so that it is possible to access the methods in that class(regardless of their positions). Normally, without a class, you need to define a method first before referencing to it. This is because python is interpreted from top to bottom

Comment: @Yatin, you can read more from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590608/is-it-possible-to-forward-declare-a-function-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You need to add self throughout the class, passing it to each method and using it when calling the methods and referring to variables.

```
class RPS:
    def main(self):
        print ("Let's play some RPS.")
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.compTurn()

    def compTurn(self):
        compRo11 = 1

        if compRo11 == 1:
            compRo11 = 'rock'
        elif compRo11 == 2:
            compRo11 = 'paper'  
        elif compRo11 == 3:
            compRo11 = 'scissors'

        print(compRo11)

    def usrTurn(self,compRo11):
        pass

rps = RPS()

rps.main()
```